# Can't build release iOS Cordova app with taco / remotebuild

Tags: cordova, taco

Using taco and remotebuild on a cloud mac, I'm trying to do a release build of my Cordova app :

```
taco build ios --device --release
```

The remote machine has an iOS distribution signing identity and provisioning profile. When creating the provisioning profile I chose Distribution -> Ad hoc, and specified my device.

The build starts and fails with:

> Command finished with error code 2:
>   /Users/user118804/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11611/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build
>   --release,--device,--device ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:
>   /Users/user118804/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11611/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to build this project Failed to build app for
>   buildNumber 11611:
>   /Users/user118804/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11611/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2 Remote build log written to
>   C:\Repos\Canvass\Canvass.Mobile\remote\ios\release\build.log TACO5629:
>   Remote build failed Inner Error: Remote build error from the build
>   server Build failed with error
>   /Users/user118804/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11611/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2

I'm not really sure where to look for more details. My dev builds work fine.

Comment: The error trace specifies "Remote build log written to C:\Repos\Canvass\Canvass.Mobile\remote\ios\release\build.log"  Did you checked there for any clue?

Comment: The log is huge - here is where it starts looking bad leading up to the build failure http://pastebin.com/SKxBww0t

Comment: From the log I m guessing that you are using push plugin. Could you remove the plugin once and try building so that we can narrow down the issue

Comment: Thanks. I removed the plugin and did taco build ios --clean --device --release and it works. I wonder what it's not happy with.

Comment: @user888733 Gotta dig deep to get into the root of the issue. So does it solve your purpose? I can post the answer?